# Which is the "correct"/"official" kernel version? (server vs cloud-img installs)

Tags: server, kernel, cloud

I recently used official images to install bare metal servers and VMs (using a cloud image) and found out they install quite different kernels out of the box:

- 14.04.4 server iso (from [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/trusty/ubuntu-14.04.4-server-amd64.iso)) installs "Wily" kernel 4.2
- 14.04.4 cloud-image (from [here](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-disk1.img), "daily" build 20160512) installs original "Trusty" kernel 3.13

I understand that [both are supported as of 14.04.4](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/FAQ#Kernel.2FSupport.A14.04.x_Ubuntu_Kernel_Support) (which is great!) and that [I can upgrade them](https://askubuntu.com/a/236458/145568) but this still begs a couple of questions:

1. Which should be installed by default?
2. Should it be different for the baremetal ISO vs the cloud image?

I ran into this because I'm trying to simulate a baremetal environment with VMs for testing purposes and assumed that images listed above would yield a reasonably similar environment...

(note: although this q relates to 14.04.4, I suppose the question might apply to future point releases, eg: 16.04.x later)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this link will help you: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the link.  It's similar to the link I quoted above.  I don't think it answers the questions, specifically not the second one...